# Finding every occurrence of a class and removing that class

Tags: jquery

This will find everything within id="myID" that has class="myClass" and remove class="myClass":

```
$('#myID').find('.myClass').removeClass('myClass')
```

Q: Is there a shorter way of accomplishing the same thing? I just want to double check my syntax to make sure that I'm doing it the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search descendants in the selector and not use `find()`

```
$('#myID .myClass').removeClass('myClass')
```

Comment: He'll likely get slightly better performance with his original code

Comment: I'd post the jsperf, but, its underwater. I've seen a tiny performance difference, but, not super huge